# Trouble with Model.IsValid on a property thats not required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, viewmodel, poco

I am having trouble with Model.IsValid on a property that's not required.

Here's the code.

BeginForm in the Edit.cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/formdata" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("_MemberForm", Model.Member)
}
```

MemberEditViewModel: (used for the Edit.cshtml file)

```
public class MemberEditViewModel
{
    public MemberFormModel Member { get; set; }        
}
```

MemberFormModel:

```
public class MemberFormModel : ICreateMemberCommand, IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public int PinCode { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public char Gender { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string ZipAddress { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }        
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    //not required (but still displaying error it's required)
    public Membership Membership { get; set; }

    // not required (displaying error it's required)
    public PunchCard PunchCard { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

block of _MemberForm.cshtml (partial)

```
   <fieldset>            
        <dl>
            <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</dd>

            <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PinCode)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PinCode)</dd>

            <!-- problem with membership, maybe with the .FromData/ToDate ? -->
            <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Membership)</dt>   
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Membership.FromDate, new { @name = "Membership" }) - 
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Membership.ToDate, new { @name="Membership"})</dd>

            <!-- problem with punch card, maybe with the .Times ? -->
            <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PunchCard)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PunchCard.Times, new { @name = "PunchCard" })</dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
```

The MemberController Edit Action

```
    // POST: /Members/10002/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection formValues, MemberFormModel memberForm)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        if(IsSaveOperation(formValues)){
            if(TryUpdateMember(memberForm)){
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Member", new {id = memberForm.Id});
            }
        }

        var mm = new MemberEditViewModel{ Member = memberForm };
        return View(mm);
    }
```

Membership.cs

```
public class Membership
{
    public Membership(){ /* empty constructor */}
    public Membership(int id, int memberId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        MemberId = memberId;
        FromDate = fromDate;
        ToDate = toDate;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

PunchCard.cs

```
public class PunchCard
{
    public PunchCard() { /* empty constructor */ }
    public PunchCard(int memberId, int times, DateTime createdDate, DateTime modifiedDate)
    {
        this.MemberId = memberId;
        this.Times = times;
        this.CreatedDate = createdDate;
        this.ModifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int Times { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

You see I dont have any [Required] attribute, neither in the MemberFormModel. So how come those two are Required ? Its a mystery.

Comment: I added ModelState.Remove("PunchCard.Times") in the Edit Action and that solved the problem, but is there another solution ? I tried the [Bind(Exclude)] attribute but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using both the `disabled` and `readonly` attribute on your textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I guess the disabled attribute takes precedence and the value of the Id is never sent to the server when you submit the form. That's why you get a modelstate error. Because your id property is required. Now you will be probably tell me that it is not decorated with the `[Required]` attribute but this doesn't matter. Since you have declared it as a non-nullable integer it is implicitly required and the framework automatically makes it required. If you don't want this to happen you should declare it as a nullable integer.

So back to your view, if you want to only display id, without allowing the user to modify it, use readonly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Obviously don't think that if you made a textbox readonly, the user cannot modify it. The normal user will not. But a hacker could always put whatever value he wants in this textbox and forge a request. So absolutely do not rely on this as some sort of security or something.

Comment: thx for the heads up Darin, but what for the Membership and Punch Card ? Why are they required when not having the [Required] attribute ? When I used the ModelState.Remove it works, but i get this date in the Membership From/To 0001-01-01 00:00:00, any ideas ?

Comment: worth mentioning is that I removed the disabled attribute, but still not working with Membership and PunchCard so that was not the problem. The problem are those two. I have checked the ModelState.

Comment: You haven't shown your custom editor templates for those 2 types, nor how those types look like so it is hard to tell.

Comment: I don't have any custom editor templates at all. Look above to see how the types looks. I will update.

Comment: You don't have custom templates? What's the point of using `new { @name = "PunchCard" }` then? Also I don't see the definition of the `PunchCard` anywhere in your question.

Comment: Put the following in your POST action: `var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Errors = string.Join(",", x.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)) }).ToArray();`. Now put a breakpoint. And inspect the value. You will see which fields failed validation.

Comment: The field FromDate is required, the field ToDate is required, the field PunChard is required is the results.